# WordPress malware returns Even After Deleting and Reinstalling WordPress Afresh

Tags: wordpress, web, malware, wordfence, infection

Hello Wordpress experts,
I have been facing a problem with my wordpress website and don't just know what to do again.

I have removed wordpress malwares from several site successfully before now but this particular site is totally confusing right now. I have tried every means possible to the extent that I had to backup the site and delete it and to my surprise, having installed a fresh wordpress installation leaving it for some minutes, the malware files we're recreated again. Now I don't know where this is coming from as I was not expecting a fresh wordpress site to get infected immediately.

I've checked the plugins, themes, replaced wordpress corefiles, scanned with wordfence, and the one that is above all I deleting the whole site and reinstalling a new wordpress and yet getting these files recreating themselves again after few minutes the fresh wordpress was created.

Comment: Malware might be coming from other sites on the server if it's a shared hosting, or they may be installed outside of the WP directory. Or, if you're reinstalling the same theme / plugins from a backup after installing that fresh WordPress copy these may be infected already.